# Send NSURLConnection request multiple times with different url's in a for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop, nsurlconnection, geocoding

I have an array of addresses that I need to convert to Lat/Long using Google's Geocode api. I am feeding an address and the city into the Google Geocode URL, which forms a correct connection url.

Basically I want to be able to use a for loop to create multiple NSURLConnection requests, returning multiple responses.

```
-(void)setString{
 for (int i = 0; i < [businessArray count]; i ++)
{         
NSString *address = [addressArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *city = [locationDict valueForKey:@"city"];
NSString *geocodeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@,+%@,&sensor=true", address, city];
    geocodeURL = [geocodeURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:geocodeURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
    geoCodeConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


    if (geoCodeConnection)
    {
        responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        connectionIsActive = YES;
        NSLog(@"connection active");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"connection failed");
        connectionIsActive = NO;
    }

}
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    NSString *responseString    = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *jsonError          = nil;

    SBJsonParser *json          = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *parsedJSON    = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&jsonError];

    NSString *lat= [[[[parsedJSON valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString *lng= [[[[parsedJSON valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"];

    NSLog(@"lat = %@ long= %@", lat, lng);
    connectionIsActive          = NO;
    [geoCodeLatArray addObject:lat];
    [geoCodeLngArray addObject:lng];
    NSLog(@"geoCodeArrayLat: %@", geoCodeLatArray);


}
```

Right now the code returns only the last address' lat and long. How can I send multiply requests and return multiply responses with JSON?

Comment: In addition to that , you didn't use int i inside the for loop , it should come in `NSString *address = [addressArray objectAtIndex:i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I  am using this,

```
for(int i=0;i< businessArray.count;i++)
{
    NSString *address = [addressArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *city = [locationDict valueForKey:@"city"];
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", address, city];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:address];
    // then here store the location.latitude in lat array and location.longitude in long array.
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

    NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

    NSDictionary    *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];
    NSDictionary   *geometryDict = [resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];
    NSDictionary   *locationDict = [geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];

    NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"];
    NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];

    NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"];
    NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [latString doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [lngString doubleValue];

    return location;
}
```

Update to the above function:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;
    return location;
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is exactly the answer for an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) example. 1. It's using a  method `stringWithContentsOfURL:` which *shall not* be used for accessing *remote* resources. 2. This method is *synchronous* and possibly blocks the main thread and thus the UI. 3. The latter will be multiplied by the fact that this method is used in a loop. The actual problem hasn't been addressed.

Comment: So I tried this, and for the purposes of geocoding ~10 addresses, this works fine. I would assume any large connection would not be very efficient with this, but this works just fine. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Spenciefy, see my updated code, it is better that the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You might approach the problem using an asynchronous method that performs the request and has a completion block which will be called when the result is available. This completion block provides a parameter *result* which is the result of the connection request.

This method may be declared as follows:

```
typedef void (^completion_block_t) (id result);

- (void) fetchGeoCoordinateForAddress:(NSString*)address 
                    completionHandler:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;
```

Say, if the request succeeds the parameter *result* in the block is a JSON representation of the response data. Otherwise, *result* is an NSError object indicating the error. But the exact details depend on how you implement the method `fetchGeoCoordinateForAddress:completionHandler:`.

Now you can setup the loop as follows:

```
for (NSString* address in addresses) 
{
    [self fetchGeoCoordinateForAddress:address completionHandler:^(id result) {
        if (![result isKindOfError:[NSError class]]) // check if result is an error
        {
            // Note: result is not nil and is a NSDictionary representation of JSON.

            // Retrieve the "location" from the response:
            NSDictionary* location = result[@"results"][@"geometry"][@"location"];

            // Multiple request can occur at the same time! Thus, we need to 
            // synchronize access to the result array "myLocations" through 
            // accessing it *exclusively and everywhere* on the main thread:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.myLocations addObject:location];
            });                
        }
        else {
            // got error
            DebugLog(@"ERROR: %@", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: your actual code may differ slightly depending on the actual JSON and other details.

Regarding the implementation of method `fetchGeoCoordinateForAddress:completionHandler:` you have a few options:

1. Use a third party library and implement a simple convenience wrapper `fetchGeoCoordinateForAddress:completionHandler:`.
2. Create your own "MyHTTPConnectionOperation" class that encapsulates a `NSURLConnection` and the response data and couple of other useful state info in a dedicated class. This class executes the request asynchronously via `start` method and has a completion handler. Basically, all third party network libraries will use this approach. Then implement the wrapper.
3. Use NSURLConnection's asynchronous convenient method if it is sufficient and works in your context. This is the fastest to implement, but least flexible approach and may not work in all cases and may also work only suboptimal.

Edit:

A couple of hints:

- If possible, use `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing JSON and creating a Foundation representation. Other third party libraries only offer a slight advantage if you have special requirements, e.g. you need "chunked parsing with NSData objects" - which is useful when you want to download and parse simultaneously. Or you need to create other representations than Foundation - say a C++ container or you want directly create a Model with SAX style parsing. Or, you need better performance and lower memory food print since you are receiving ultra large strings which you want to save to disk. `NSJSONSerialization` became quite fast recently, so "performance" alone shouldn't be an argument today.
- The timeout for the request shall be not that low as 10 seconds. In a cellular connection, this is too less. Leave it at the default.
- If you plan to implement your own "HTTPConnectionOperation" class, I've put a very limited sample on gist [here](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723) which can give you a jump start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start with AFNetworking

[AFNetworking1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/afnetworking-1-0/)
[AFNetworking2](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking)

because  AFNetworking gives a lot of power and flexibility in terms of scheduling and **queueing** requests as well as pausing and cancelling requests.